# XAML Namespace Beginning with a Number

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, namespaces

I have inheritted `Button` and am trying to add it to my main window.

It doesn't show up in the `Toolbox`.  I have tried rebuilding several times.

I have tried adding `xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:123Letters` and `xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:123Letters;assembly=123Letters` to my `MainWindow`.

My `MainWindow` is:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="MainWin"
        Title="123 Letters">

</Window>
```

My `WeatherStationButton` is:

```
<Button x:Class="WeatherStationButton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Button>
```

and

```
Public Class WeatherStationButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Property WeatherStation As tblWeather
End Class
```

This is super simple stuff.  I believe it's because XAML doesn't allow numbers in the first part of namespaces, but I can not find any reference to that **anywhere**, so I am asking if I am doing something wrong or is this one of XAML's "features"?

Comment: I was right.  XAML does secret magic with namespaces that begin with numbers.  You have to add an underscore before the first number, like: `_123Letters`.  I have no references for that other than my trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I could add my answer.

If your project name is `123Letters`, you need to add an underscore before the first number when referencing it in XAML like, `_123Letters`.

Your `clr-namespace` declaration would then be:

```
xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:_123Letters"
```

and you could add your inherited button to your MainWindow like this:

```
<dc:WeatherStationButton x:Name="btnWS" />
```